# ArcSDE how to Change Allow null values to "NO"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog, null, sdelayer

I have created a few feature classes on an SDE using ArcCatalog and initially when I created them I set "Allow null values" to yes. I was wondering if this can be changed back to "No"? It is ArcSDE 10.0 on Oracle 11g. I need to disallow null values to minimise the amount of time spent on QC of null values inserted by default by the user.

See attached screenshot

[image: ArcSDE allow null values (ArcCatalog)]

Comment: The "Allow NULL values" is a *field* setting, not a *feature class* setting.  When adding new fields you can change this option, but I don't believe you can change it after the field has been created (without deleting and recreating the field)

Comment: Disallowing NULL will **not** force the user to enter a value.  All this does is force ArcGIS to save an empty string `""` instead of `<Null>`, so you're replacing one problem with another

Comment: My idea was to disallow null and apply a domain to the field so the user can simply choose the value. Faster than typing.

Comment: Data is *never* stored in "SDE" (which no longer exists). The proper term of art is "Enterprise Geodatabase", but you still need to specify **exactly** which database (and complete version), which can change answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can change the *Allow Null values* setting without recreating the field.  You can **not** add a new field with *Allow Null values* set to `No` on a feature class that contains records.

In response to your comments, your idea to disallow Nulls and have a domain will still not force users to input a value.  If they don't pick a value from the Domain, it will just be an empty string `""` instead of a `<Null>`

To test I created a new feature class in my database (running on Microsoft SQL Express).  The first field `MyField1` disallows Nulls, and has a domain.  The second field `MyField2` disallows Nulls and has no domain, and third `MyField3` allows Nulls and also has no domain.

[image]

I created three points, and left some of the fields blank.  I was able to do this on all three fields, it doesn't force me to input on any field.

[image]

As you can see when I use the Identify tool on the points, `MyField1` is blank (not `Null`) and `MyField3` is `Null` - both of these fields I left blank when I added the point, it honoured the No Nulls by saving an empty string.

[image]

Even if you set the attribute window to pop up on feature creation (Editor > Options > Attributes), it still won't force you to enter any values, so Nulls/Blank values are still a possibility.

[image]

When *Display attributes dialog before storing new features* as enabled, it pops the attributes window up as soon as I create the point, but I can just click on OK to close it.

[image]

Comment: Dropping the table and recreating it is the supported mechanism. Sometimes you can use ALTER TABLE, but then you need to re-register the table with both the geodatabase and every service or map document is accessing it.

Comment: I remember a hack where you  apply the domain to the field and set a default value on the field that is NOT in the domain. I think regular editing workflows will flag the value as invalid, thus forcing the user to pick a different value from the domain

Comment: Interesting idea although in my experience domains do no validation which is why you can calculate any value in via field calculator. That said I'll give it a try later

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Seems the only way is to create new feature class. I tried the method stated by Ben and it did not force the user to choose from the domain on ArcMap 10.0. The domain was text based and I set a default value to something not in the domain. I will probably think about getting ESRI data reviewer once we upgrade 10.3.